# how to choose a row when the row number of that row is equal to the value of the other column with duplicates in R?

Tags: r, row, row-number

I have a data frame as follows -

```
df <- cbind(c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3), c(6,12,18,3,9,12,4,8,12,16),c(3,3,3,2,2,2,4,4,4,4))
colnames(df) <- c("ID","value","index")
```

I want to get the following result -

```
df1 <- cbind(c(1,2,3), c(18,9,16),c(3,2,4))
```

So I basically want to extract (for each ID) the row whose row number is equal to the index for that ID. For example, the 3rd row for ID 1, 2nd row for ID 2 and 4th row for ID 4.

I tried the following code

```
df1 <- df%>%group_by(ID)%>%filter(index==index)
```

But it is not working. Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `slice` to select the `index` row for each `ID`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% slice(first(index)) %>% ungroup

#     ID value index
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1    18     3
#2     2     9     2
#3     3    16     4
```

This can be written in `data.table` and base R as :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[first(index)], ID]

#Base R
subset(df, index == ave(value, ID, FUN = seq_along))
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3), 
                 value = c(6,12,18,3,9,12,4,8,12,16),
                 index = c(3,3,3,2,2,2,4,4,4,4))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just adding to the Ronak Shah's answer, I guess one of the straightforward codes to do what you want is the following:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- 
    data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3), value = c(6,12,18,3,9,12,4,8,12,16), index = c(3,3,3,2,2,2,4,4,4,4))

df %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(row_number() == index) %>% ungroup
```

Comment: your answer worked as well...Thank you very much